# jQuery form validation and Update Panel

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, validation

I am using updatepanel in asp.net web form with .net framework 4.0. In between, I implemented jquery form validation. It's working well with the form validation but the problem occurred with the update panel cannot do partial postback but fully postback. Appreciate for any reply.

I have something like this, do validation on form and do show some image when update panel initialize request.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".logForm").validate();
        $('#main_UpdatePanelAccount').initializeRequest(function (options) {
            $("#flashAcc").show();
            $("#flashAcc").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="/image/load.gif" align="absmiddle">');
        });
    });
</script>
```

After this, I have this 2 blocks of code (one with commented and another with uncommented) to determine whether postback or not. However this 2 blocks of code also end with the update panel fully postback.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(instance_initializeRequest);
    function instance_initializeRequest(sender, args) {
        if (!Validator()) {
            args.set_cancel(true);
        }
    } 

//    $(function () {
//        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
//        //Re-initialize jquery after an auto post back.
//        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
//            //Do work after update panel fires.
//            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
//            if (!Validate()) {
//                prm.abortPostBack();
//                args.set_cancel(true);
//            }
//            else {
//                prm.add_beginRequest();
//                args.set_cancel(false);
//            }
//        }
//    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly if your code is inside the updatepanel, it's going to get wiped out on postback. Unrelated to your question but just a side note. Secondly unless you set updatepanel to updatemode="conditional", it will also update all content in other update panels as well. If you are still getting a full page refresh, I would try doing it this way instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
    function Post() {
        __doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel1.ClientID  %>', '');
    }
 -->
 </script>
```

Comment: ya currently with the right mode the block of codes located outside of update panel :)